# How to Get Text Of Selcted index in datalist tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want inner text of `option` tag with pure js

Here is my HTML

```
<input list="in" name="i_n" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Item Name" required>

<datalist id="in" onChange="rate(this)">

    <option value='value'>Inner Text</option>

</datalist>
```

Here is my script

```
function rate(sel)
{
        var a=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
        alert(a);
}
```

And there is no message in Console.

Comment: Your function at the HTML is named `cost()` and at the JS is named `rate()`. When do you invoke it?

Comment: Thank You ! But Problem still same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Using Datalist Wrong Way!..
DataList is not select Tag Both are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#in option').each(function(index) {
    var a = $(this).text();

    alert(a);
});
```

OR

```
$("#in option:selected").text()
```

Comment: Thank You But I have to Use Pure JS not Jquery !

Comment: @PremThAqqar You should edit your question to note that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get the value of datalist.

```
document.getElementById('int').addEventListener("change",function () {
   var g=this.value;
   alert(g);
});
```

Here is the working [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vccfv/230/)

Comment: Thank You !! But I have to Use Pure Js.

Comment: I want a inner Text Not Value

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the corresponding `datalist` textContent via attribute selector:

```js
inputEl.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  let datalistId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('list');
  let datalistOption = document.querySelector(`#${datalistId} option[value="${e.currentTarget.value}"]`);
  
  currentSelection.textContent = datalistOption ? datalistOption.textContent : '';
})
```

```css
label {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label id="currentLabel">Current Selection: <span id="currentSelection"></span></label>
  <input id="inputEl" list="mydatalist" placeholder="Enter Item Name">
</p>

<datalist id="mydatalist" onChange="rate(this)">
    <option value='item1_value'>Item 1</option>
    <option value='item2_value'>Item 2</option>
    <option value='item3_value'>Item 3</option>
</datalist>
```